# Getting S3 File Create / Update Dates in Athena Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Are there any built-in athena functions that will show the underlying S3 file create / modify date for a given row in a query result?  We have a large data lake with many different file formats and it would be hard to add this information to them all.

Answer (score 6):

This feature is now available using athena engine 3, field name is called `$file_modified_time`

```
select "$file_modified_time" from tablename
```

It's quite simple to migrate from v2 to v3 under the assumption you don't have any unsupported queries, you should follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions-changing.html) guide

Answer (score 2):

According the PrestoDB documentation here https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#extra-hidden-columns the fields are added but at the time of this post they are not yet available in Athena.

According to the documentation the answer to your question would be the modification date of the file, that can be retrieved with the **$file_modified_time** variable.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Athena supports the Presto `$path` pseudocolumn, which shows the **name of the file** from which the row was obtained, eg:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "$path" FROM table
```

There are requests to add more pseudocolumns to Presto, such as **Last Modified** and **File Size**, but (at the time of writing this answer) they are not available in Presto. Once they are in Presto, they *might* find their way to Athena after some time.

See:

- [Pseudocolumn for "last modified" date · Issue #1423 · trinodb/trino](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/1423)
- [Add Pseudo-column for fileSize and fileModifiedTime by Praveen2112 · Pull Request #1428 · trinodb/trino](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/pull/1428)

Comment: Thanks John.  That 2nd link you send seems like it may have been resolved (committed) 28 days ago, is that correct?  I'm not sure how to interpret Github.

Comment: Hi, Could anyone please inform me if something has occurred regarding this? i haven't seen any progress on this last modified field exposure :(

Comment: Looks as if they've implemented it in `prestodb` but it's not yet supported in Athena https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/16055